# How to mute chat from enemies

Tags: dota-2

Is it possible to mute general chat in Dota 2 so that you won't see messages from enemies but keep chat from allies enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mute individual players in the [Score Board](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Head-up_display#Scoreboard) via the small speaker icon next to the player name.

There is no specific option to disable enemy chat by default.

Comment: But from what I can see on screenshot from you link you can mute only players from your team. Or is it a modified screenshot?

Comment: Well, if not, its obviously a bug and should be noted.

Comment: there is also a checkbox to mute the whole textchat that appears when you press enter, you can mention that aswell

Comment: @Demarsch on the screenshot, the opposite team is composed of Bots that cant be muted

Comment: @WizLiz that is what I don't want. I want still to see messages from allies, and that checkbox blocks everything